# Forecast evaluation for rolling forecast

Tags: forecasting, model-evaluation, moving-window

I have rolling forecast for each month. I would like to do some forecast evaluation. How do I do this?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't used to the website and didn't know about these things. Thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you can do forecast evaluation in, and it is up to you what to choose. I will give an overview of the possibilities.

1. You can assess **absolute** forecast accuracy using measures such as mean squared error (MSE), root mean squared error (RMSE), mean absolute error (MAE), mean absolute percentage error (MAPE) and similar. (MAPE is in a sense a relative measure, but *not* in the same sense as used in the next point.)
2. You can assess forecast accuracy **relative** to a benchmark forecast using mean absolute scaled error (MASE) or Theil's $U$ statistic (be aware that there exist different definition of this statistic in the literature). Employ Diebold-Mariano test to see whether the loss due to forecast errors from one forecast is as large as the loss due to forecast errors from another forecast. Use forecast encompassing test to see if given a benchmark forecast there exist another forecast that improves upon it.
3. You can assess forecast **optimality** using forecast optimality tests. For time series forecasts you may start with the following four optimality conditions. First, an optimal forecast is unbiased; hence, the forecast errors have a zero mean. Second, one-step-ahead forecast errors are white noise. Third, $h$-step-ahead forecasts are at most an MA($h-1$) process. Fourth, variances of $h$-step-ahead forecast errors are non-decreasing in $h$. However, checking these four conditions requires the number of forecasts to be not too small. If you only have some 10 or 20 forecasts, you cannot expect high precision/confidence in your answers. Besides the four optimality conditions above there is Mincer-Zarnowitz test dealing with predictability of forecast errors.

This brief overview is mainly based on Diebold "Forecasting in Economics, Business, Finance and Beyond" (version of 4 October 2016) (Chapter 11 "Evaluating Forecasts" and Chapter 12 "Combining forecasts") freely available [here](http://www.ssc.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/Teaching221/Forecasting.pdf) and my unpublished research paper (not yet publicly available). Clearly, you will find a much broader discussion of each of these measures and tests in Diebold's textbook.

Comment: Nice answer, but suggesting OP that he could find information in not yet published and not available paper does not seem to provide much help...

Comment: @Tim, of course, pointing to a non-existent references would be strange. Therefore, I said he should look for more information in Diebold's textbook (and did not point to the unpublished paper). However, I had to acknowledge the true sources, which I did by also mentioning the paper.