# How to compare forecast performance of two subsamples?

Tags: forecasting

I need to compare forecasting performance of two subsamples. I need to evaluate whether a change that was introduced improved the forecasting performance i.e., compare the forecasting performance between pre-change period and post-change period.  How would I be able to do this?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you have a loss function associated with the forecast errors, you can compare the average loss before policy change to the average loss after the policy change by a two-sample $t$-test or similar.

Comment: You should of course adjust the $t$-test for the possible dependence of observations in the samples of forecast errors, e.g. the possible MA($h-1$) pattern in $h$-step-ahead forecast errors as mentioned under point 3. [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175602/forecast-evaluation-for-rolling-forecast/175755#175755). (The idea for adjustment should be similar to using HAC standard errors in regression when the residuals are not i.i.d.)